# I'm using mongoose in my Node JS project and I need to move an object from a certain array to another array

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose

I have a collection in my database with the following data structure demonstrated in the code below. Basically, it is an array of lists and each list has its own array. I am currently using Node JS along with Mongoose. On the front end this is displayed in the form of a kanban. So the user can move a card from one position within the same list, for example, from position 3 to position 0 or can move a card from one list to another, going from list A to list B, and in list B it it must be added in position 4 for example, and this object can no longer be present in list A. This is similar to Trello. I want to know how to do this using the mongoose. Can someone help me?

```
const leadsList = [
  {
    listID: "A",
    cards: [
      {
        id: "card-1",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      },
      {
        id: "card-2",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    listID: "B",
    cards: [
      {
        id: "card-3",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      },
      {
        id: "card-4",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Currently, I am using the following function to resolve this. As you can see, I'm getting the entire collection, making a deep copy of leadsList, manipulating the copy, and then saving the manipulated copy again. As this will be a common operation, and these lists can have thousands of objects, it can be very expensive to do it this way. I would like this to be done directly at the bank, without the need to deal with the entire document.

```
async moveCard(req, res) {
    const { flowID } = req.params;
    const { from, to, fromList, toList } = req.body;

    try {

      const leadsCollection = await Lead.findOne({ flowID });

      if (!leadsCollection) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "Erro ao buscar usuário." });
      }
    
      const updatedLeadsList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(leadsCollection.leadsList));
      const cardToMove = updatedLeadsList[fromList].cards.splice(from, 1)[0];
      updatedLeadsList[toList].cards.splice(to, 0, cardToMove);
    
      const result = await Lead.findOneAndUpdate(
        { flowID },
        { $set: { leadsList: updatedLeadsList } },
        { new: true }
      );
    
      if (!result) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: "Erro ao buscar usuário." });
      }

      return res.status(200).json({ message: "Card movido com sucesso."});
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: "Erro ao mover card." });
    }
  }
```

It must be possible to move a card position within the same list, or move from one list to another list in a given position. In the example below I am simulating moving "card-1" from list "A" to position 2 of list "B". Note that the object must literally be moved, that is, it is no longer present in the "A" list.

```
const leadsList = [
  {
    listID: "A",
    cards: [
      {
        id: "card-2",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    listID: "B",
    cards: [
      {
        id: "card-3",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      },
      {
        id: "card-4",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      },
      {
        id: "card-1",
        createdAt: "",
        variables: []
      }
    ]
  },
]
```

Comment: You may want to have a look at [`pull`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/)  and [`push`](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

Comment: I looked but didn't find anything in this documentation about dealing with nested structures like this.